# jquery how to find the correct url on a Get method I use mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, get

I was basically using Jquery inside my mvc4 razor page and thus I could use url.action like this

```
$.get('@Url.Action("details","user")'
```

I have now moved my jquery to an external file and I obviously can not user razor helpers to get the correct URL, how can I get that same url from an external js page, I have tried a few new ways and it does not work like this

```
$.get('~/Controllers/user/details')
 $.get('~/user/details')
```

I would like how to find this without using a global variable, I have seen many websites use it like

```
$.get('details.html')
```

but since this is mvc that does not work, any help would be great

The routes are standard MVC routes

```
         routes.MapRoute(
        name: "profile", // Route name
        url: "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
        defaults: new { controller = "profile", action = "detail", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

                 );
```

Comment: Can you provide your routing configurations?

Comment: Yes just put the route above in the new edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your route (see the `Global.asax`) You need to provide the absolute url, such as `http://yoursite1.com/user/details` which is not a good practice because of dependancy. If the website/route changes, then you must change your js files.

**BEST PRACTICE**

What you need to do is to define a function in your external file and call it inside your view,  as follows

In your view.cshtml

```
<script src='script.js'> </script>
<script>
         doByGet('@Url.Action("details","user")');
</script>
```

script.js

```
function doByGet(url){
   $.get(url)
}
```

Comment: It is a pleasure (y) !

Answer (score 0):

this is how we do in our application ( I know you said without global variables but I find the idea quite viable)

External File (.js)

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + 'YourActionMethod',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json'

});
request.done(function (data) {

    if (data != null) {
        //do whatever

    }
});
```

in CSHTML

```
<script>
   baseUrl = '@Url.Action("PlaceHolder", new { area = "YourArea", controller = "YourController"})';
   baseUrl = baseUrl.replace('PlaceHolder',''); //Remove placeholder from baseUrl, alternatively you may place blank in first statement
</script>
```